I installed a "security update" and now the system cannot find my printer
I installed a "security update" and now the system cannot find my printer. When I try to find or add a printer, I get the message; Sorry, The system printing service doesn't seem to be available.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. As is, your Question lacks actionable information.

If one puts that error message into a web search, there are a few hits (even if some of those remain unanswered). Nevertheless, I found one relatively actionable thread, even if it's for Arch linux. Maybe it points towards a useful direction: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165862

Thanks to those who responded, however, the ...help/how-to-ask and ...help/formatting were more confusing than helpful. The info from 8-10 years ago, also did not help. I made an edit to my original post indicating that I can't find anything named systemct1 and I was unable to connect to http://localhost:631.

"I can't find anything named systemct1." It's systemctl ('L', not 'One"). Try again.

"I was unable to connect to localhost:631" Avoid vagueness. Tell us exactly what you input, and show us the complete output. Maybe your printing service simply is not running. But maybe other possibilities. It's up to you to provide enough detail to make your question answerable.

"..help/how-to-ask and ...help/formatting were more confusing than helpful." You must be able to clearly describe the problem to folks who are not in the room with you and cannot see your screen. If you cannot, then we won't be able to help you.

Thank you again to those who answered my call for help. I apologize for my misinterpreting systemctl (lowercase 'L') as systemct1 (numeral '1'). You recognized my mistake and after pointing it out, I realized that I made that mistake many years ago in dealing with a Unix based system. When I mentioned trying 'localhost:631' I meant trying http://localhost:631/admin. I've tried that again and still get the response "No connection." The good part is, my system has connected to my printer once again after several days of not being able to do so and I'm able to print normally. Very confusing!

What I actually tried was, http://localhost:631/admin. The response was "Unable to connect." It still does this. I have no firewalls and I didn't/don't used a proxy.

Looks like we have issues at both upstream - https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/985 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/2070315 for the ubuntu packages
A regression update was released to fix this specific issue : USN-6844-2
You can upgrade and make sure the versions match with USN-6844-2
